# What is the RedisCacheManager.setExpires() equivalent in spring-data-redis 2.x

Tags: spring-mvc, redis, upgrade, spring-data-redis, jedis

I'm in the process of migrating my spring MVC project from spring 4 to spring 5. As a part of that task, I'm trying to upgrade spring-data-redis 1.8.13.RELEASE to 2.7.12.
Spring Cache Configuration logic which I have mentioned below is the impacted area since the spring redis version upgrade.

Current code: (spring 4 / spring-data-redis 1.8.13.RELEASE)

```
@Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisHost);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisPort);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword(redisPassword);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(redisTimeout);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setUseSsl(redisSslEnabled);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(new JedisPoolConfig());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

        Map<String, Long> cacheRegionTtls = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        String[] regions = cacheRegionTtlList.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
            String[] region = regions[i].split(":");
            cacheRegionTtls.put(region[0], Long.valueOf(region[1]));
        }
        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setExpires(cacheRegionTtls);
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(defaultCacheTtl);
        return cacheManager;
    }
```

Upgraded code (currently inprogress): (spring 5 / spring-data-redis 2.7.12.RELEASE)

```
@Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHost);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisPort);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);

        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration
                .builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisTimeout));
        if (redisSslEnabled) {
            jedisClientConfiguration.useSsl();
        }
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling().poolConfig(new JedisPoolConfig());

        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, jedisClientConfiguration.build());
        
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {

//cacheRegionTtlList is a string variable which contains list of values, with the format of cacheRegion:ttlInSeconds,cacheRegion:ttlInSeconds
        
        Map<String, Long> cacheRegionTtls = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        String[] regions = cacheRegionTtlList.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
            String[] region = regions[i].split(":");
            cacheRegionTtls.put(region[0], Long.valueOf(region[1]));
        }

        Duration defaultCacheTtl= Duration.ofSeconds(defaultCacheTtl);

        return RedisCacheManager.builder(factory)
           .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(defaultCacheTtl)).build();
    }
```

I have a few questions:

1. Up to now have I followed the recommended way of code logic to upgrade into spring-data-redis 2.x?
2. Since `cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(defaultCacheTtl)` method has been removed in spring redis 2.x, can I achieve the same by `RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(defaultCacheTtl)`?
3. Since `cacheManager.setExpires(cacheRegionTtls)` has been removed in spring redis 2.x, whats the alternative new way I can achieve that? (Please suggest me a code modification for my upgraded code)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get a solution ?